# PHP Equivalent of Java Type-Casting Solution

Tags: java, php, casting

Since PHP has no custom-class type-casting, how would I go about doing the PHP equivalent of this Java code:

```
CustomBaseObject cusBaseObject = cusBaseObjectDao.readCustomBaseObjectById(id);
((CustomChildObject) cusBaseObject).setChildAttribute1(value1);
((CustomChildObject) cusBaseObject).setChildAttribute2(value2);
```

In my case, it would *very* nice if I could do this. However, trying this without type-casting support, it gives me an error that the methods do not exist for the object.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Is it possible that the methods are not declared in the object? Because if they aren't, you will get that error....

Comment: Are the methods declared in the child object? Yes, they are. I just can not access them in a PHP situation like this because it doesn't anticipate the right type for the child object. Hence, it throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to make `cusBaseObjectDao::readCustomBaseObjectById()` a factory that produces the appropriate child. After that there's no need to cast because PHP is a **dynamic language**.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you just call methods. The type is a runtime attribute:

```
$baseObj = $baseObjDao->readById($id);
$baseObj->setChildAttribute1($value1);
$baseObj->setChildAttribute2($value2);
```

Java is statically (and strongly) typed. PHP is dynamically (and weakly) typed. So just call methods on objects and if it's not the right type, it'll generate a runtime error.

Comment: The problem is that for the second and third lines, the base object actually needs to be a child object. Otherwise, it will say the method does not exist because the readById() method returned the base object not child object.

Comment: @stjowa not sure I understand what the problem is. `readById()` can return an instance of *any* class. Shouldn't it return one of the right type (the one with those methods)? If not, I'm missing something. What is Java doing that you expect?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was correct to include/couple child-related information in a base DAO... but, I guess that was my problem in this case. In Java, I *could* have done something similar to what I wrote in my question by explicitly casting it to the child, but this is a limitation in PHP. Thanks.